# Ionic 2 Promise - Finishing the first process before executing the second process

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

For my Ionic 2 project, I have two functions executing one after another. Each function consists of an API call. I want to wait until the first function finishes executing everything before going to the second function.

The issue I'm having is that since the first function takes some time to finish, the second function executes before the first function finishes executing.

I'm learning how to use Promise as I was told it can solve this issue.
I've simplified the code so it's easier to follow:

```
const first = () => {
  self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/GetPersonalCalendarData',
    {
    }, result => {
      result.Data.forEach(lAppointment => {
      });
    });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });

};

const second = () => {
  self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/AddPersonalAppointment', {
  }, result => {

  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
};

first().then(() => {
  return second();
});
```

Comment: I added a delay to my first function and my program seems to work. But this is not an efficent way:
` return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500);
      });
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your post inside the `new Promise`:

```
const first = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/GetPersonalCalendarData', {
            }, result => {
                result.Data.forEach(lAppointment => {});
                resolve();
            });
    });

};

const second = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/AddPersonalAppointment', {
        }, result => {
            resolve();
        });
});
};

first().then(() => {
     return second();
});
```

Or return directly the promise generated by the POST

```
const first = () => {
    return self.pspService.post('url, {}, result => {
            result.Data.forEach(lAppointment => {});
            return Promise.resolve(result);
        })
}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet worked for me. I just misplaced the promise wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new HttpClient and switchMap to get a unique Observable

```
firstAndSecond(){
    return self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/GetPersonalCalendarData')
          .switchMap((data:any)=>{
            //there you have "data", you can use to change the post
            return self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/AddPersonalAppointment')
           });
}
//In your component
myService.firstAndSecond().subscribe((data2)=>{
    //data2 it's only the data from self.pspService.post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async**/**await** to handle exactly such scenarios.Asynchronous functions are prefixed with the **async** keyword; **await** suspends the execution until an asynchronous function return promise is fulfilled and unwraps the value from the Promise returned.

```
async func(){
    const first = () => {
      self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/GetPersonalCalendarData',
        {
        }, result => {
          result.Data.forEach(lAppointment => {
          });
        });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
      });

    };

    const second = () => {
      self.pspService.post('/api/Conversation/AddPersonalAppointment', {
      }, result => {

      });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
      });
    };

    let firstValue = await first();
    console.log("First Value", firstValue);
    let secondValue = await second();
    console.log("Second Value", secondValue);
  }
```